# #define NULL NULL

Tags: c++, c, null, macros

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL NULL
#endif
```

This code compiles in gcc with no warnings/errors.  Can someone explain what the preprocessor is doing here?

Comment: NULL doesn't mean undefined in C/C++ ...

Comment: This probably beats #define SIXTY_NINE 69. http://bugpwr.blogspot.com/2007/07/magic-numbers-in-code.html

Comment: try to do: 
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL 0
#endif

Comment: @TripleS - I'd never do this in production code.  I just saw it somewhere and thought it was interesting and worth thinking about.

Comment: actually I saw it too somewhere... I'd not use it as final solution. It's said that at the beginning of C++ NULL was defined  as a zero.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Anywhere the compiler sees the text "NULL" it will replace it with the text "NULL". It's like doing a search-and-replace in your code for "NULL" and replacing with "NULL". Not illegal, just weird :)

Comment: I think it's important to note that it's almost certainly not doing this unless NULL is undefined.  NULL is usually defined, so this block probably doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 16):

The only possible reason for doing this would be to do it *before* including header files which themselves do something like

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL (void *)0
#endif
```

This would then stop the NULL from being defined like that.

Comment: Sir, I approve of your avatar.  I have not thought of Lemmings in a long time.

Comment: Doesn't that just raise the even more mysterious question of why you'd want to stop NULL from being defined in some other header?

Comment: This question is also tagged C++, and in §5.1.1 of his book, Stroustrup recommends the following definition: `const int NULL = 0;`

Answer (score 5):

It's normal:

```
#ifndef JON_SKEET
#define JON_SKEET JON_SKEET
#endif
```

This compiles too. This is because the preprocessor simply does mindless replaces. What it replaces and what it replaces with don't need to be valid identifiers.

Think of it like this: open your editor's Search & Replace window and type in "NULL" in both the `Replace` and `Replace with` fields. It won't give any error or warning and it will "work", even though it actually doesn't do anything. The preprocessor does the same thing.

Obviously when you try to use it:

```
'JON_SKEET' undeclared (first use in this function)
(Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
for each function it appears in.)
```

Comment: Yes, but blocks like that generally imply that the *fact that the symbol is defined* is what matters.  Pretty strange to be doing that for NULL.

Comment: Not really, it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen cases where code like this brings a value from the compiler namespace ("namespace" in general, not C++ `namespace`) to the preprocessor namespace, *e.g.*:

```
// In the compiler namespace, not in the preprocessor namespace
static int const FOO = 1234;

// Bring the constant into the preprocessor namespace as well
#ifndef FOO       // <---- FOO really is undefined here.
#define FOO FOO
#endif
```

Really ugly stuff.

Personally I haven't found a use for this sort of thing, but exists nonetheless.

---

**EDIT**:  While I've seen this, I don't know why it would be useful, other than check if "`FOO`" defined as a preprocessor symbol somewhere else in the code; perhaps in dealing with some legacy code.  Anyone?

Comment: Hmm, I thought I had a use there for a moment, but then I realised it was wrong. If FOO is already defined, then it will have been replaced in the line `static int const FOO = 1234;`. I have no idea why you would be prepared to carry on under those conditions. `#define FOO FOO` potentially makes sense, as you say, if you're replacing a macro with a constant but don't want to change some old code that checks for it being defined. But letting FOO be defined to something else when you're defining constant FOO sounds like trouble to me.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly this isn't being used as a macro, it's being used as a compilation flag.  Are there other areas of the code where you see `#ifdef NULL` or `#ifndef NULL`?

It is very strange to use "NULL", specifically, as such a flag, but I've seen stranger (`#define TRUE FALSE`)...

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question of what the preprocessor is doing:

Unless there's preceding code that undefs NULL, it's skipping the `#define NULL NULL` completely.  NULL is almost certainly already defined. In C++, the use of 0 is preferred due to C++'s tighter type-checking.  If you must use NULL, it's best to declare `const int NULL = 0;` (see Section 5.1.1 of Stroustrup).

Answer (score 0):

doesn't that simply define NULL as the character sequence "NULL" ?

Comment: No. It would be `#define NULL "NULL"`

Comment: Be careful when you say character sequence and use quotes, since it might seem you are referring to a c-string character array `"NULL"`.